# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: while writing output to a file in Python3.7

Tags: python, json

I am trying to write & append json data retrieved through the API calls to a file. 'missed_loc_id' is a dataframe of single column with identifiers. Below is the python code.

```
df_loc_missed = pd.DataFrame( columns=['location_id', 'city', 'country'])
json_arr = []

url_loc_missed = "https://europa.eu/v1/locations{id}"
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}

for row in missed_loc_id.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):
    id = row.location_id
    url_loc_missed = f"https://europa.eu/v1/locations/{id}"
    
    miss_loc_response_api = requests.get(url_loc_missed, auth=('hghgh', 'ghghgh$'), headers = headers)
    miss_loc_api_json_resp = miss_loc_response_api.json()
    json_arr.append(miss_loc_api_json_resp)
    
    with open("missed_location.json", "a", encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
        json.dump(json_arr, myfile, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
        myfile.close()
```

However, after few successful writing and appending the data to the outfile, I get following error.

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'missed_location.json'
```

Any help is highly appreciated to resolve this issue.

Comment: the only time ive seen this error is when I have whatever I am writing to open.

Comment: What makes you think you *should* have permission to open this file for appending?

Comment: dunno the root cause is the this but .. since you are opening the file with context manager (with keyword) - you are trying to close the filehandle twice - remove the `myfile.close()` and check if that fixes it ?

Comment: @rasjani I think closing an already-closed file is a no-op. The redundant close shouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: Please show the full traceback so we can see which line gets the error.

Comment: You shouldn't have the code that writes to the JSON file inside the loop. You should build the entire array in the loop, then write it once to the file. You're writing multiple copies of the array to the file. But this isn't related to the error.

Comment: Why would you append to a json file? that will break the format of the file. Also. you do not need to close the file if you use `with open(` . Permission anyway is related to other issue. check if the file already exists and was created by a different user.